# Batch script: how to check for admin rights

Tags: batch, command-line, administrator

How do I check if the current batch script has admin rights?

I know how to make it call itself with runas but not how to check for admin rights. The only solutions I've seen are crude hack jobs.

Comment: @Bobby: That was asking how to do it in bash though.

Comment: @Jason404: Wtf?! How the hack did I misread Batch for Bash? oO' @Tilka: My sincere apologies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could always do something like this

```
mkdir "%windir%\system32\test" 2>nul
if "%errorlevel%" == "0" (rmdir "%windir%\system32\test" & echo Is admin) else (echo Not an Admin)
```

Not the best of ways but works for me all the time.

Comment: This is a hack job which the OP is trying to avoid.............

Comment: @Pacerier I think that's a joke! there are less invasive options like [net](http://superuser.com/a/204779/391675) and [fsutil](http://superuser.com/a/1174827/391675)

Answer (score 4):

After some research (mostly on SO<sup>[1]</sup>), I found that `net` is not always a good solution, it can show false negative results. But there is `fsutil` available for WinXP to Win10. It's worth reading the whole insightful answer ***"More issues"*** to the question [Batch script: how to check for admin rights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051883/batch-script-how-to-check-for-admin-rights/21295806#21295806) there.

Here's the short answer for hurried users:

```
fsutil dirty query %systemdrive% >nul
if %errorlevel% == 0 (
    echo Running with admin rights.
) else (
    echo Running without
)
```

---

<sup>[1]</sup> my actual problem was elevation, but ***non-invasive checking*** is part of it:

- [command line - How to request Administrator access inside a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894967/how-to-request-administrator-access-inside-a-batch-file)
- [windows - How can I auto-elevate my batch file, so that it requests from UAC administrator rights if required?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7044985/how-can-i-auto-elevate-my-batch-file-so-that-it-requests-from-uac-administrator)
- [windows - How to detect if CMD is running as Administrator/has elevated privileges?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7985755/how-to-detect-if-cmd-is-running-as-administrator-has-elevated-privileges)
- [windows - Batch script: how to check for admin rights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051883/batch-script-how-to-check-for-admin-rights)

Comment: really like it as it doesnt rely on any networking service - needed something 100% and this does it - btw knowing your drive isnt dirty is good aswell :o)

Answer (score 0):

This is the best kludge I could think of, using standard commands:

```
net user %username% | findstr /r Administrator.
if %errorlevel% == 1 (
echo This is not an admin account
) else (
echo This is an admin account
)
```

Comment: That doesn't work when you are in a domain. And when I tried "net user %username% /domain" the Local Group Membership section didn't contain any groups although I have local admin rights. Strange...

Comment: Plus the output is localized.

Comment: Besides, one can run a batch file without administrator rights from an account who is in Administrators group (this especially relates Vista/7).

Comment: Well, also [net sometimes fails](http://superuser.com/a/1174827/391675)

Answer (score -1):

You just need this one line at the top of your batches that require elevation. emphasis on "One Line"

> nul 2>&1 fsutil dirty query %systemdrive% || echo CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^).ShellExecute "%~0", "ELEVATED", "", "runas", 1 > "getadmin.vbs" && "getadmin.vbs" && exit /b

Comment: This doesn't work. It causes an infinite number of `cmd` shells to be opened.